# Replace characters at a specific index counted from behind

Tags: sed, replace

I want to change some characters in a string I create. I make a filelisting and from each file I need to append the "stat" information. For example filename   `"K181_111126.CATProduct"` results in `"K181_111126.CATProduct.2011-11-28 13:33:33.722342000 +0100"`. The last 16 characters I don´t need, I solved it with:

```
find . -type f -exec stat -c%n.%y {} \; | sed 's/.\{16\}$//'
```

Result: `"K181_111126.CATProduct.2011-11-28 13:33:33"`
My problem is, that I need to change the space (9th character from behind) between date and time with a "-" and all ":" in the time (13:33:33) with a dot "."
The strings all have different length, so that I can only count from behind.

Comment: please format your question for clarity.. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: If you have a GNU-based system, you might find it easier to start from `find`'s built-in `-printf` date-time options e.g. `find . -type f -printf '%f.%Tx-%TH.%TM.%TS\n' | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//'`

Answer (score 2):

Replace the space and the colons at the same time by using a slightly longer regex.

```
find . -type f -exec stat -c%n.%y {} \; |
sed 's/ \(..\):\(..\):\(..\).\{16\}$/-\1.\2.\3/'
```

The space before the 24th character from the end is matched, then we match and capture the next 2 characters, a comma, the next 2, a comra, and another 2; then, the last 16 are matched and replaced with nothing. The first captured expression can be recalled using a backreference `\1` (the second with `\2`, etc). In other words, the two digits after the space are "replaced" with themselves, i.e. effectively retained, followed by a dot, the next two, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$ s='K181_111126.CATProduct.2011-11-28 13:33:33.722342000 +0100'
$ echo "$s" | rev | sed -E 's/.{16}//; s/:/./; s/:/./; s/ /-/' | rev
K181_111126.CATProduct.2011-11-28-13.33.33
```

This uses `rev` to reverse input line character wise so that it is easier to process and finally `rev` again

- `s/.{16}//` delete first 16 characters
- `s/:/./; s/:/./` change first two `:` to `.`
- `s/ /-/` change first space to `-`

Answer (score 0):

```
find ... |
sed -Ee '
  s/.{16}$//
  :a;s/:([^:[:blank:]]*)$/.\1/;ta
  s/[[:blank:]]([^[:blank:]]+)$/-\1/
'
```

Where after the deleting the trailing 16 chars just as you did, we setup a loop to progressively convert the `:` -> `.` and when done, change the last most blank char to a dash. This is necessary as the filename may also comprise blank chars and we need to ignore those.